# How to pass variables from a Robot Test script to Python script

Tags: python, robotframework

Robot Test

```
*** Settings ***
Variables   test_if_case_sensitive.py
Documentation    Suite description
Library     Process

*** Variables ***
${pw1}   "HeLLo1234"
${pw2}   "hello1234"
${test3}

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    ${test1}=    set variable   ${passwordWithCaps}
    ${test2}=    set variable   ${passwordWithoutCaps}
    ${test1}=    set variable   ${pw1}
    ${test2}=    set variable   ${pw2}
    ${test3}=    set variable   ${message}
    Start Process   python3     test_if_case_sensitive.py
    Check If It Works
*** Keywords ***
Check If It Works
   PASS EXECUTION IF    ${test3} == "Passwords do not match"
```

Here is the python script

```
#test_if_case_sensitive.py
import socket
import string
import random

global passwordWithCaps
global passwordWithoutCaps
global message

def randomString(stringLength):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

def test_check_if_passwords_match_case_sensitive_when_creating_them(passwordWithCaps, passwordWithoutCaps):
    username = randomString(random.randint(10, 20))

    confirm_password = False
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    IP_address = "127.0.0.1"
    Port = 8081
    server.connect((IP_address, Port))

    while True:
        message = server.recv(2048).decode("utf-8")
        if message:
            print("Message 1" + message)
            if confirm_password:
                print("Message 2" + message)
                if message.__contains__("You have successfully registered"):
                    raise Exception("Passwords match when they shouldn't")
                break
            if message.__contains__("Please enter username"):
                server.send("--register".encode())
            if message.__contains__("Please enter a username to register"):
                server.send(username.encode())
            if message.__contains__("Please create a password"):
                server.send(passwordWithCaps.encode())
            if message.__contains__("Please confirm password"):
                confirm_password = True
                server.send(passwordWithoutCaps.encode())

            print(message)

test_check_if_passwords_match_case_sensitive_when_creating_them(passwordWithCaps, passwordWithoutCaps)
```

I am trying to assign global variables passwordWithCaps and passwordWithoutCaps from the Robot Test script using variables ${pw1} and ${pw2}. I instead get an error saying 'passwordWithCaps' is not defined which shows the issue stems from the python script. However, I also get this in the Robot Test -

```
Test1                                                                 | FAIL |
Variable '${passwordWithCaps}' not found.
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the Robot Framework User Guide section [Creating Test Libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries) which has practical Pyhton examples to create custom Python libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your design so far is not going to work; you are mixing the concepts of variables file with libraries. A few points where you approached it incorrectly:

- variables files are evaluated at the beginning of the suite parsing; at that point the `Variables` section is still not evaluated. When RF/python gets to the method call & tries to execute it, it is getting passed 2 vars for which it knows nothing about - apart from the fact they are in the global scope. E.g. At this point nothing but the reservation of their names is a fact for these 2 variables, nor their datatypes (how to use them), nor their values (what are they).
- the purpose of variables file is to insert in *Robot Framework's* scope new variable:value pairs; that happens with assignment operators (`variable=value`), or with the special function `get_variables()`, or with overriding the module attribute `__all__`, or with using a class (let's not get there). You have neither of those in the .py file. This might possibly be sidestepped with a `global` var scope (I haven't ever tried it) but it still needs it value set, somewhere. The reverse - inserting in the variables file scope sounds hard (if not impossible, I don't know; it might work with RF_var_the_name) - at the moment of the file evaluation there are not that many set variables, certainly no test ones.
- the variables file are evaluated only once, during the import; even if that happened at a later stage - that test function would have been ran just once, so it can be used for only one case.
- you are setting the variable `${test3}` to be equal to the `message`, the one defined and used in the function. But the scope of that variable is strictly local, it is present only for the function and only through its execution; it will never leak out (that's a python fundamental point).
- calling `Start Process` will create a new python process, totally isolated from the one running the case - and it would have no access to your variables - and `passwordWithCaps` & the other will be undefined (cause - if they were, that would have been in the case running one) & execution failing. Future tense, as we're not getting to this point at all, failing earlier.
- *(personal)* global variables are frowned upon in python, that's a dangerous (& clumsy) mechanism for communication.

So what should you *(IMHO)* do? "Separation of concerns" - fancy way of saying "have a function that does the check on one place, and the test data stored in a different place" :) 
Drop the global variables declaration and the method call from the py file, and move it to a `Library` import. Now you will have access like a keyword called "test check if passwords match case sensitive when creating them", that you can feed with *any* data.
Change its last `print()` statement to `return message` - so it can communicate with the outside world by returning the message string.

And then, in your case(s) call the keyword, with different values :

```
${test3}=   test check if passwords match case sensitive when creating them    ${pw1}    ${pw2}
Should Be Equal    ${test3}    Passwords do not match

${test3}=   test check if passwords match case sensitive when creating them    samecase    samecase
Should Be Equal    ${test3}    Passwords do not match    # will supposedly fail
```

---

*(By the way I don't see this message "Passwords do not match" ever getting out from the function, and the only thing breaking the loop is if the server has responded with success - you might want to check the flow logic there, for this negative test.)*